# DevExpress XtraGrid override from CalcRowHeight breaks RepositoryItemImageComboBox

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid, row-height

I've recently changed the rowheight for our grid and reduced it a bit (using code from http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A859.aspx).

However this breaks our RepositoryItemImageComboBox, the images are no longer shown. 
Using a RepositoryItemPictureEdit with an unbound column I can't seem to find how to create a working row filter/row sort.

Who can help me either fix the RepositoryItemImageComboBox images to show again or implement a filtering/sorting RepositoryItemPictureEdit.

This is the column shown with RepositoryItemPictureEdit, No image data on the filterrow is also a problem

[image: No image data on the filterrow is also a problem]

This is the column shown with a RepositoryItemImageComboBox.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added some code to handle the GridViews CustomDrawCell with no Editor specified. Since we don't really need the editor to choose but show the column read only it suffices.

```
Private Sub gvw_CustomDrawCell(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs) Handles Me.CustomDrawCell
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(BitMap, e.Bounds);
end sub
```

Comment: Added advantages of this way to work is that the UnboundColumnValue will be shown as 'filter' options.